# Is there a way to monitor review queues on SO, SF, & SU without having to maintain a separate browser tab for each?

Tags: discussion, review

Is there a way to monitor the review queues from a single page for SO, SF, and SU? Would it be inappropriate to create my own page with say 3 iframes on it that would reload each page in a frame?

Just looking for ideas on how to check the queues more frequently.

Comment: I use a tab for each queue as well. That has never been a problem for me though I am interested in seeing a **master** queue of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

I recently released a userscript I wrote for the purpose, which you can find at [Stack Apps](//stackapps.com/questions/6869/review-stalker-reloaded). It loads selected sites' review pages in an endless rotation, and also loads review queues if they have anything in them. If you use it for SO, it will probably tend to starve other sites somewhat until you cap most of your daily reviews, although it won't go more than an hour at a time without checking all sites.